# Rendering VUE router links with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i want to create an app that renders links dynamically with v-for and opens different components with each link.
I know how to render the `<router-link>` itself ,But I don't know how to dynamically change the destination url of the `to=""` prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array looks for example like this:

```js
components: [
  {
    path: "/a",
    name: "Component A"
  },
  {
    path: "/b",
    name: "Component B"
  }
]
```

You can use it in `v-for` like:

```html
<router-link
  v-for="(comp, i) in components"
  :key="i"
  :to="{ path: comp.path }"
>
  {{comp.name}}
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using bind `:to="{path: '/to'}"` in `<router-link>`.

Comment: thank you it was somewhat helpful as i didn't know i have to bind the 'to' . but what about the path? how do i define the dynamic path?